# Show that this is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1(C)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the curve

$$u^2+v^2+w^2= 0$$ in $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)$. How do I show it is isomorphic to $ \mathbb P^1 ( \mathbb C)$?

Comment: This equation is not homogeneous, perhaps you meant $w^2$ in place of $w^3$?

Answer (score 2):

The required isomorphism from $\mathbb P^1$ to the conic $V\subset \mathbb P^2$ with equation $u^2+v^2+w^2=0$  is :$$f: \mathbb P^1\stackrel \cong \to V:[x:y]\mapsto [u:v:w]=[2xy:y^2-x^2:i(x^2+y^2)]$$

**Edit**
The inverse isomorphism $f^{-1}:V\stackrel \cong \to \mathbb P^1$ is given by : \begin{cases}
&f^{-1}([u:v:w])=[x:y]=[u:v-iw]\quad \operatorname {if} \quad[u:v:w]\neq [0:1:-i]=:\omega \\  
&f^{-1}(\omega)=[1:0]\\
\end{cases}
The isomorphism $f^{-1}$ is the projection of the conic $V$ from its point $\omega$ onto the line $w=0$ identified with $\mathbb P^1$ *via* $[x:y:0]\leftrightarrow[x:y]$, and all the calculations leading to the formulas above were dictated by this geometric picture.